# strcat to concatenate a and b without actually changing a or b

Tags: c, string, concatenation, strcpy, strcat

I know I can have a statement as such

```
    strcat( a, b );
    int alen = strlen( a );
    printf("a and b concatenated = %s and its length is %d\n", a, alen );
```

However, I want to preserve a, so I am trying use something more like this:

```
    strcat( a, b );
    int xlen = strlen( x );
    printf("a and b concatenated = %s and its length is %d\n", x, xlen );
```

How do I fix the first line with strcat so that it concatenates a and b into x?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the following :-

```
strcpy(x,a);
strcat(x,b);
int xlen = strlen(x);
printf("a and b concatenated = %s and its length is %d\n", x, xlen );
```

Voila,and that's it.

Comment: Thank you, that is simple enough.

Comment: there is an important detail to always check.  Specifically, is the length of 'x' large enough to hold strlen(a) + strlen(b) +1

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following as works as well:

```
    /* Concatenate a and b */
    char x[SIZE1+SIZE2] = “”;
    strcat(x , a );
    strcat(x , b );

    printf("a and b concatenated = %s and its length is %d\n", x, (int)strlen(x) );
```

Comment: if SIZE1 and SIZE2 are related to strlen(a) and strlen(b) then the result is not large enough, because strlen() is the offset to the trailing NUL byte so need to add +1 to get the proper length.  Also, the first line causes x[0] to contain '\0'.  it does not clear all of x[]. suggest using: ;char x[SIZE1+SIXE2+1] = {'\0'}; to clear the whole array and to not generate a literal (containing only a '\0' character) in readonly memory